# Eclipse Android Common XML editor cannot switch between modes

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Somehow I switched from standard WYSIWYG mode for Android Common XML Editor to text mode. I heard that there suppose to be a tab in the bottom of the screen to switch (Layout/file.xml), but I guess in Eclipse Juno there isn't one. My question: how to change between WYSIWYG and text modes in Eclipse Juno?

[image: Screenshot of Eclipse URL]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> to navigate to the previous page (which is what you need right now) and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> to navigate to the next page of a multi page editor.