# Eclipse is missing Graphical Layout and Source tabs when editing Android XML files

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, graphical-layout-editor

When I edit XML files in Eclipse using Android Common XML Editor I am only able to use the graphical layout editor.  I see in pictures online how there are supposed to be tabs at the bottom for Graphical and Source but I have none.  How do I get this fixed?  Using Eclipse 4.2.1.  Thanks!

Comment: which operating system do you use ?

Comment: can you upload a screenshot of your eclipse screen ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is [probably a problem of Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394089/eclipse-android-common-xml-editor-cannot-switch-between-modes) not displaying the editor correctly. I bet that you can still switch between the tabs using the keyboard. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> to navigate to the previous page and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> to navigate to the next page of a multi page editor.

Comment: Shift+Alt+F7 works thank you!  Still wish I could get the tabs working but at least I have a working solution!

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem so far.

Solution:

==> In your Layout editor there is a android version configuration dropdown box, from there select proper android version. (Eg. "Android 2.3.3")

try this and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that this problem occurs after installing custom theme for eclipse. In my case it was "Dark Juno" theme. Bring back original theme and everythink will be all right again :-)

------ EDIT ------

You can use MoonRise dark theme ( https://github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme ). Bottom bar works perfectlly and design looks good.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to use OpenWith ->Layout Editor on the xml file witch u want to open from project explorer under res folder

Comment: My options are Android Common XML Editor, XML Editor, Text Editor, System Editor, Default Editor, Other

Comment: then you can try to delete project, without deleting the source files and do File>Import>Existing Projects into Workspace, and select your project

Comment: check also this: Window-->Preferences-->Editors-->File Associations-->.*XML--->set this as Default one---->ok

Comment: No change after restart either... this is frustrating!

Comment: it seems that your eclipse is corrupted. In eclipse go to help and choose 'Check for updates' Let him install all the updates that were found. Then eclipse should restart and hopefuly you will be able to see all the tabs