# Eclipse: Tabs below androidmanifest.xml are missing

Tags: android, eclipse

When I open androidmanifest.xml from the left panel, it is missing the "Manifest", "Application", "Permissions", "Instrumentation" and "AndroidManifest.xml" tabs along the bottom that I see in tutorials. How do i make the tabs appear?

[image]

Comment: Try to open Using Android manifest Editor, right click -> Open with ->Android manifest editor

Comment: This is a common problem, this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756416/eclipse-is-missing-graphical-layout-and-source-tabs-when-editing-android-xml-fil) will solve your problem.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click on the android manifest file. \
2. Then open with "Android Manifest Editor"
3. You will then be good to go.
   To switch back to the 'normal' editing mode, click on the 'AndroidManifest.xml' tab.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Press Shift+Alt+F7 to navigate to the previous page and Alt+F7 to navigate to the next page of a multi page editor.